# Shortest string containing all substrings of fixed length(any 1 permutation of the subset) of a list of characters

Tags: string, algorithm, graph-algorithm

If I am given a list of characters say {s1,s2,s3,...,s10}, I want to find a string of shortest length having all unordered subset combinations of length three occurring as substrings within the string. For example, if I consider the subset { s2, s4, s9 } then I would be able to locate atleast one instance of a string containing those three characters in any order as a substring. There are no repeats, as in it is not required to include a substring of the form 's1s1s1'.

Comment: Nice assignment. What have you done so far?

Comment: Not better than brute, which isn't worth posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this problem using the [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) constraint solver:

```
%  dimensions
int: N = 10;  %  number of characters
set of int: Characters = 1..N;
int: L = 416;  %  length of shortest string

%  decision variables
array[0..L-1] of var Characters: shortest;

%  every unordered subset must occur somewhere in shortest
constraint forall(a, b, c in 1..N where (a < b) /\ (b < c)) (
    exists(i in 0..L-3) (
        ((shortest[i] == a) \/(shortest[i+1] == a) \/ (shortest[i+2] == a)) /\
        ((shortest[i] == b) \/(shortest[i+1] == b) \/ (shortest[i+2] == b)) /\
        ((shortest[i] == c) \/(shortest[i+1] == c) \/ (shortest[i+2] == c))
    )
  );

%  to speed things up, we enforce the first N entries
constraint forall(i in 0..N-1) (
  shortest[i] == i+1
);

%  further speedup: adjacent entries are probably different
constraint forall(i in N..L-2) (
  shortest[i] != shortest[i+1]
);

solve satisfy;

%
%  Output solution as table of variable value assignments
%%
output 
[ show(shortest[i]) ++ " " | i in 0..L-1 ];
```

For character sets with 5 characters, a solution is found instantly:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 4 1 3 5 2 4
```

But for more characters, let alone 10, the search takes too long to be practical.

I noticed that the minimum length seems to roughly double for every additional character.
For 3 characters, the length is trivially 3. For 4 characters, it is 6 and for 5 characters 13. But I could not find a solution for 6 or more characters.

I found a related paper [On strings containing all subsets as substrings](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78901577) which confirms my finding for 5 characters. But the paper was published back in 1978. More recent discoveries might exist.